# CSS text wizard / style library for a photoshop guy

Tags: css

I am looking for a 'one-stop' solution/tool to give a Photoshop guy who knows nothing about CSS as a means for him to choose fonts and styles that can be made as CSS.

I'm looking for something very similar to this '[CSS Font and Text Style Wizard](http://www.somacon.com/p334.php)', but that will also allow for changes to color, backgrounds, be friendly to a 'Photoshop guy' and preferably have built in styles.

Any better tools out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fit the bill: http://www.typetester.org/

The link to generate the CSS style is a bit hard to find - it's just to the right of the sample text box

Comment: this is pretty much exactly what i wanted. thanks. different font list categories useful too. only bonus thing would have been prebuilt styles but this shoudl be good enough for him to play with

Answer (score 2):

You can start with the oh-so-limited but [web-safe font list](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html) and the standard CSS [text decorations](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_text_text-decoration.asp). Then move on to the CSS [box model](http://redmelon.net/tstme/box_model/). You're better off learning how to "really" do it than depend on a tool

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://www.blueprintcss.org/ , it's not a wizard, it's a code base which has lots of predefined values.

If he has no clue about css, I think it's better for him to have a consistent basis like blueprint or http://960.gs and overwrite only the typography and other parts he needs, with help of w3schools docs and some wizards like the one you mention.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like Microsoft Frontpage or Adobe Dreamweaver. Generating CSS styles for text only is a really narrow problem domain for a full-fledged application. Aside from perhaps some online scripts, you're not likely to find any programs designed with such a limited scope.

Like Diodeus said, anyone who's interested in doing web design should just learn some basic CSS. If 13-year-olds on Myspace can do it, than so can a "Photoshop guy." Otherwise, just get a WYSIWYG editor. That's what they're there for.

But honestly, the CSS involved in styling text is so simple & basic that if that's *all* you want to do, then it's hardly worth buying (or even installing) an HTML editor. There are maybe 10 commonly used tags that you need to know (if that), and they all have the same 15-20 attributes that are related to text appearance/formatting.

The web is literally overflowing with online guides & tutorials for CSS/HTML aimed at every level of programming proficiency. Anyone who spends even 2 weeks reading/following them should be able to pick up everything that you are talking about, and then some.